# Is it ok to use UIPasteboard in a background thread?

Tags: ios, uipasteboard

Is UIPasteboard thread safe ?

I am trying to do something like this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
     UIPasteboard *generalPasteBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
     NSData *settingsData = [generalPasteBoard dataForPasteboardType:@"SomeType"];

    if (settingsData == nil) {

        UIPasteboard *pasteBoard = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"SomeName" create:YES];
        settingsData = [pasteBoard dataForPasteboardType:@"SomeType"];
    }   
    // Do something with settingsData
});
```

Is this safe to do or should I use UIPasteboard only on the main thread ?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are trying to use it off the Main thread? In the example you've given, you could keep the UIPasteboard stuff on the Main thread, and only dispatch_async at the point where you need to do some processing of it. UIPasteboard is not thread safe, and as it's a UIKit class, I'd err on the side of caution and not touch it from off the Main thread if possible.

Comment: In general, UIKit is not thread safe and most UIKit work must be done on the main thread.

Comment: It takes about 100ms to read the pasteboard and its eating away some of my cold startup time. That's why I was wondering if I could throw it off to a bg thread.

Comment: maybe I could do a dispatch_async and then sync it on the main thread ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using it on a background thread on iOS 9 and 10 with no issues. As the pasteboard accesses global, shared system resources, I would assume it to be thread safe, even though it is in the UIKit framework. Obviously there is no documentation to back me up, just my own experience.

Example code, using a category I created for MBProgressHUD:

```
typedef void (^ImageBlock)(UIImage* image);
#define DISPATCH_ASYNC_GLOBAL(code) dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{ code });
#define DISPATCH_ASYNC_MAIN(code) dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ code });

+ (void) pasteboardImageWithCompletion:(ImageBlock)block
{
    // show hud in main window
    MBProgressHUD* hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAnimated:YES];
    DISPATCH_ASYNC_GLOBAL
    ({
        UIImage* img = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].image;
        if (img == nil)
        {
            NSURL* url = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].URL;
            if (url == nil)
            {
                NSData* data = [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] dataForPasteboardType:(NSString*)kUTTypeImage];
                img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            }
            else
            {
                img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
            }
        }
        DISPATCH_ASYNC_MAIN
        ({
            block(img);
            [hud hideAnimated:YES];
        });
    });
}
```